# How to store list of static data in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, static

I am working on a website and I want a drop-down to display the list of cities. Where should I store the list of cities for faster access? I do not want to store this data in DB.

Is it a good idea to store it in XML file?

Comment: Faster than what? You can store it anywhere - memory, disk, webservice etc - but tell us the requirements first.

Comment: you could just save it in a List<cities> in your codebehind ? that  would be ugly code tho..

Comment: If you can't hold it in memory then there is nothing much faster than a DB.

Comment: @juergend Text files are an order of magnitude faster that a DB.

Answer (score 3):

I would store it in Cache, possibly with a Sql Dependency or File Dependency.

```
public DataTable GetCities(bool BypassCache)
{
   string cacheKey = "CitiesDataTable";
   object cacheItem = Cache[cacheKey] as DataTable;
   if((BypassCache) || (cacheItem == null))
   {
      cacheItem = GetCitiesFromDataSource();
      Cache.Insert(cacheKey, cacheItem, null,
      DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(GetCacheSecondsFromConfig(cacheKey), 
      TimeSpan.Zero);
   }
   return (DataTable)cacheItem;
}
```

If you want to store it in XML, that's fine too but you'll have to publish the file to all servers in the farm each time there is a change.

Answer (score 1):

Store it in a text file. This avoids the overhead of XML parsing. Load using `File.ReadAllLines()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the list in an XML file or other flat file format, but I guess it depends on what your reasons are for not wanting to store it in the database.

You mentioned faster access, but you might want to expound on that. If you mean you don't want the overhead of accessing the database on every request, then have you thought about storing it in the database and caching the list on application start-up instead? This way, you get the benefits of a database, yet only pay the overhead once.

For small applications, however, an XML file would be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the list will never change, then just declare it as a const array of strings in your code.

If it may change occasionally, then put it in an xml file or a database table, but cache it when you have read it so it only needs to be read once in any session.

Answer (score 0):

I believe XML is the best solution, and it would be better to use DOM parser rather than SAX.

You can also load the file into the session whenever it is not loaded to decrease the number of reads of the XML, but this will use more RAM on the server, be sure not to load unnecessary data because it will be loaded into the server's RAM for each session. You can load it only for logged in users if it makes sense.

Comment: XmlReader is a pull-parser, not a push-parser like SAX. XmlDocument is not a good choice, unless you're stuck with .NET 2.0. You want [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

What I'm about to suggest is HORID style, but I think the quickest you can get and with the smallest "footprint":

```
public static readonly string [] CityList = new string [] 
{
  "Sydney",
  "New York",
  "London"
};
```

Now, I hope you don't like the solution, and can give us all a little more context so that we might be able to offer an elegant and maintainable solution to your problem; but if all your after is speed...